# Sprite deformation in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I would like to ask what the best way to deform a sprite dynamically as below is?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: you have draw this using OpenGL. override the draw function and change the vertex.

Comment: if the answer helped you, upvote, by all means. If it is the best one you got, then accept it too. (if i could, i would :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2012/03/soft-body-physics-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-24/

Above link is a tutorial for soft body physics but you can get the same deformation idea from this tutorial that how is he drawing the circle. check "draw" method.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. And I also found another way by subclassing CCGrid3DAction.

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial will probably help you if you're using cocos2d v3.x: http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2014/05/soft-bodies-with-cocos2d-v3.html